# where do i write my responsive styles in bootstrap v3.0.21

Tags: html, css, styles, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a little confused by the new BS and it's already set styles. I need to write some responsive styles and see that there is in the grid.scss file the large, medium, and small media queries which is where i placed all my responsive styles but as I got stuck in writing them in there... it then didn't work. Large styles appeared in the small view. Dam!

An example of my code is here:

```
// Small grid
//
// Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the small device range, from phones
// to tablets.
//
// Note that `.col-sm-12` doesn't get floated on purpose--there's no need since
// it's full-width.

@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
  .container {
    background-image: url("../images/graphics/splash-mobile.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 320px;
    min-height: 653px;
    margin-top: 45px;
  }
  .splash h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .splash h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
  }
  .splash h3, .splash p {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  } 

  .form-signin {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
  }

  .splash .btn-block {
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    width: 32%;
  }

  @include make-grid-columns-float(sm);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, sm, width);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, sm, pull);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, sm, push);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, sm, offset);
}


// Medium grid
//
// Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the desktop device range.
//
// Note that `.col-md-12` doesn't get floated on purpose--there's no need since
// it's full-width.

@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
  .container {
    background-image: url("../images/graphics/splash-tablet.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: $container-md;
    min-height: 605px;
    margin-top: 45px;
  }
  .splash h3, .splash p {
    padding-left: 84px;
    padding-right: 90px;
  } 
  .form-signin {
    margin-left: 13%;
    margin-right: 13%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .splash .btn-block {
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    width: 25%;
  }

  @include make-grid-columns-float(md);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, md, width);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, md, pull);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, md, push);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, md, offset);
}


// Large grid
//
// Columns, offsets, pushes, and pulls for the large desktop device range.
//
// Note that `.col-lg-12` doesn't get floated on purpose--there's no need since
// it's full-width.

@media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
  .container {
    width: $container-lg;
    min-height: 610px;
    background-image: url("../images/graphics/splash-browser.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 45px;
    padding:0;
  }
  .form-signin {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .splash .btn-block {
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    width: 25%;
  }

  .splash h2 { margin-top: 93px; padding-right: 50px; }

  .splash h3, .splash p { padding-left: 35px; }

  .form-signin { padding-left: 35px; }

  @include make-grid-columns-float(lg);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, lg, width);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, lg, pull);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, lg, push);
  @include make-grid($grid-columns, lg, offset);
}
```

Should I be writing my styles in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't make the changes to the BS files.

Create a new CSS file, put there the basic media queries and include it to your page after the bootstrap CSS. That way your styles overrule the BS styles and if there's a update available for the BS you can update the BS files without a massive hassle copy-pasting your own styles.

So create ie. `own-styles.css` and include it after `bootstrap.css`

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/own-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Add there the media queries

```
/* screen-lg */

@media (max-width: 1199px) { 
    /* screen-md */
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    /* screen-sm */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* screen-xs */
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    /* screen-xs */
}
```

And write your styles in their places.

Comment: Thanks mMoovs for your advice.